# HTML select is opened automatically on the iPhone

Tags: html, ios, html-select

A few months ago, a new feature was introduced to the iPhone/iOS that I don't like at all; when the focus is set on a HTML selection, the selection list is now always opened automatically on the iPhone, regardless of the browser. This was not the case until a few months ago. And this is not the case on a Mac, PC or any Android devices. There the selection remains unopened until you click on it.

Is there a way to modify the following code so that the selection isn't open automatically on the iPhone either?

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <select name = "myselect">
      <option value = "">[Please select]</option>
      <option value = "1">Option 1</option>
      <option value = "2">Option 2</option>
      <option value = "3">Option 3</option>
    </select>
    <p>
    <input type = "button" value = "Set focus to selection" onclick = "document.getElementsByName('myselect')[0].focus();">
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I have experienced the same thing. I sent a bugreport on email to accessibilty@apple.com with following info.

How to reproduce:

1. Pair a magic keyboard to your iphone:
   https://support.apple.com/en-ke/guide/iphone/iph4288319c0/ios
2. Go to Settings > Accessibility > Keyboards, tap Full Keyboard Access, then turn on Full Keyboard Access.
3. Open Safari browser on an iPhone (my example tested with iPhone 14 with iOS 17.1.2)
4. To experience the bug visit following showcase:
   https://mbjorke.github.io/Showcase-html-select-bug-in-iOS-and-when-full-keyboard-access-is-enabled/ (I'm the owner of this Github and the showcase was made by me)

Expected behaviour:
The third select element on the page labeled “Choose another fruit” should be able to tab to with a connected keyboard.

Actual behaviour:
The third select element on the page labeled “Choose another fruit” is not able to tab to with the connected keyboard.